# Adding Control to Control collection with Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, ascx

I've been using Telerik for the first time and have come across an issue I am unable to resolve due to my implementation. I have a MainPage.aspx that has a RadTabStrip with a RadMultiPage associated with it. Within the page views I have some user created control (.ascx) pages and have implemented them so that when a certain tab is selected the ascx page will show within the page view. I've been working on each page separately and now I'm having to work on the Search page functionality, of which I inserted a RadGrid within a RadPageLayout as seen below:

```
    <Rows>
        <telerik:LayoutRow>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:CompositeLayoutColumn Span="12">
                    <Content>
                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgSearchResults" Width="700px" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true">
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
                    </Content>
                </telerik:CompositeLayoutColumn>
            </Columns>
        </telerik:LayoutRow>
    </Rows>
```

There hasn't been any data binding, etc, all I'm trying to do is navigate to the search tab but when I do I get that frustrating error "Page cannot be null. Blah Blah Blah" I've looked online and found that I need to add the control to the controls collection of the page, but with my implementation I cant seem to find a way to do this. I've tried to add it in the "!IsPostBack" Page Load event of the search.ascx page but I get a separate error with this. And if I try to add it in the Main.aspx page it still doesn't find it... Never had this much trouble on regular asp.net/C#.. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you registered the Telerik assembly on the user control:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
```

Do you have a form with runat=server? Does the PageLayout control have its runat=server attribute?

I tried this and it showed up:

un the UC:

```
<telerik:RadPageLayout runat="server" ID="RadPageLayout1">
    <Rows>
        <telerik:LayoutRow>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:CompositeLayoutColumn Span="12">
                    <Content>
                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgSearchResults" Width="700px" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true">
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
                    </Content>
                </telerik:CompositeLayoutColumn>
            </Columns>
        </telerik:LayoutRow>
    </Rows>
</telerik:RadPageLayout>
```

in the main page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server" />
    <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip1" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1">
        <Tabs>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="first" Selected="true"></telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="second"></telerik:RadTab>
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>
    <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPage1">
        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView1" Selected="true">first page view</telerik:RadPageView>
        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView2">
            second page view with grid
            <uc1:myControl runat="server" ID="myControl1"></uc1:myControl>
        </telerik:RadPageView>
    </telerik:RadMultiPage>

</form>
```

You can also see how to work with dynamic page views and user controls here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/multipage/dynamic-pageview-creation/defaultcs.aspx. Make sure to add IDs to every dynamic control you create.

Comment: Yeah I have all of these set to runat="server", I have the telerik assembly on the Main.aspx page and the Search.ascx page. It's still not working... I'm not sure why, but my assumption is since I've been working on the UC's individually, I just recently put in the grid on the Search UC in a prior build, then try to run it and it breaks on the Search tab select.. I've already been to that page but I didn't want to have to reverse engineer anything, is there something else? I'm completely lost here...

Comment: To add on to my previous comment, I've also built the project again and again so that it knows there is a grid in there, but then again I'm thinking adding the grid after the project has already been built, even if it's been built again, is making the error happen...

Comment: Clean up the VS temp files, the ASP temp files, clean the solution and rebuild: http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/11/08/clean-up-after-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: I went through all the steps in the article, restarted visual studio, cleaned my solution, rebuilt, then built again, and still shows up with the page cannot be null error on Search tab select... What's the deal??? I had an issue like this when I was trying to utilize a custom skin on the tab strip, went through those exact steps and it worked, but for this error there is something going on so that it's not being able to show that control... I'm not sure why.

Comment: Something is probably wrong with the user control and the way the tabstrip is generated. Try from the simplest setup possible (i.e., adding everything in the markup) and start moving it closer to your setup to find the step that breaks it. If we don't have the full code we can't say much more.